# Distribution of triangular, square, and pentagonal numbers

Tags: arithmetic, visualization, experimental-mathematics

I'm doing some research in visualizing arithmetic sets (resp. properties, resp. sequences of integers). I try to create patterns (in which I hope to observe some symmetries) by injectively mapping $\mathbb{N}$ on $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ in different ways and highlighting the numbers that have a given property (belong to a given set, are in a given sequence).

You can find a little tool with which I'm playing around [here](http://syspedia.de/visualizing-properties/index.html?propertyType=2&geometryType=6).

These are three pictures I found when highlighting [square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_number), [triangular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) and [pentagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number) numbers on a spiral (like [Ulam's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral)):

[image]

and I want to ask these questions:

> How can it be explained in simple terms that the tree of square
>   numbers (originating at the center) has **two** obvious straight
>   branches, the tree of triangle numbers has **three** rather easily
>   detectable, and the tree of pentagonal numbers has **five** hard to
>   detect curved branches? Will this go on and on for arbitrary polygons? Why does the tree of square numbers not have **four** branches?

Comment: It would help if you included information on what injections you are using in the question.

Comment: I tried to explain: the injection is a spiral (like Ulam's), starting at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Ulam went to the right, from what I can see you are going up, you should state this

Comment: Is it really essential to the question?

Comment: @HansStricker , not but it is confusing and will improve the question (I'm thinking about the question regardless)

Comment: I don't quite remember my Ulam's spiral from the time I implemented it in high school, but the point was basically that every "layer" of the spiral goes from $(2n+1)^2$ to $(2n+3)^2$, hence the fact that the odd squares are all in some corner. The even ones *should* do something similar. Taking a closer look at the formula, the thing should become more apparent - like "Ah, if I plug in $(2n)^2$ the formula becomes straightforward". Pentagonal numbers have some fractional coefficient, so the thing does not work all that well.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path: I assumed that square numbers were the easy part of the question;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is taken from my answer to your [related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308449/understanding-a-group-of-transformations-of-the-plane-mathbbz-times-mathbb). The following picture from it isn't exactly your three armed spiral, but I'll venture that if you expand your central picture you will see $17$ spirals.

[image]

Comment: It obviously *is* a three-armed spiral, why do you say it isn't? Only on another level 17 arms emerge. Beautiful!

Comment: Please have a look at this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885567/distributions-of-prime-numbers).