# Distributions of prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, arithmetic, visualization, experimental-mathematics

When folding the number line not into a spiral (like [Ulam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral) did) but into a zig-zag pattern (like Cantor did) there are other patterns visible in the distribution of prime numbers:

[image]

<sub>[To see these pictures in higher resolution, you can try it out [here](http://syspedia.de/visualizing-properties/index.html?propertyType=3&geometryType=1&squareType=1) and [here](http://syspedia.de/visualizing-properties/index.html?propertyType=3&geometryType=1&squareType=2). Note that these are two different zig-zag patterns (with different "lattice parameters").]</sub>

One sees diagonal bands with an above-average density of prime numbers. One of them contains the prime numbers $7, 11, 29, 43, 73, 89, 131, 157, 181, 211, 239, 379, 421, 461, 601,\dots $.

> How can these bands be explained?

One also sees a rather distinct band from the lower left going upwards at an angle of roughly $75°$. It contains the prime numbers $229, 271, 317, 367, 421, 479, 541, 607, 677, 751, \dots $.

Note, that the vertical and horizontal borders of the pattern contain no primes at all, which can be easily understood.

<sub>[See my [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2884854/how-to-understand-these-pictures) concerning the distributions of other numbers.]</sub>

---

<sub>By the way (and off the record): The detecting of lines in patterns (most easily of straight lines) is fun also in non-mathematical contexts (be them obvious or not):</sub>

[image]

<sub>[Giotto (ca. 1267 – 1337) Entombment of Mary](https://www.smb.museum/en/museums-institutions/gemaeldegalerie/events/detail.html?tx_smb_pi1%5Bevent_id%5D=94612&cHash=10fa8206cb2e95ad3953464d1d4f51d4)</sub>

Comment: I think it's still more or less the same effect that the Ulam spiral illustrates: that some quadratic expressions generate more primes than one might expect.

Comment: Yes, in principal, more or less. But Ulam-like coverings of $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ (spirals) may exhibit higher level *spirals* (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2885571/1792)), while Cantor-like coverings of $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ may exhibit *straight lines along arbitrary angles* (as can be seen above). Both long for different explanations I guess (see Aarons explanations [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/308512/2672)).

Comment: The first sequence you described corresponds to [A081352](https://oeis.org/A081352) (polynomials $n^2+3n\pm 1$), while second seems to be contained in [A007641](https://oeis.org/A007641) (polynomial $2n^2+29)$. Maybe it won't be too hard to show that each line will corresponds to one or more such polynomials.

Comment: The [Bunyakovsky conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture) is related (generalization of Dirichlet's theorem to generic degree polynomials)

Comment: Ah, A081352 is even called "Main diagonal of square maze arrangement of natural numbers". The question is: Why does already the **main** diagonal produce primes? The other way around: How probable is it that a polynomial of degree 2 produces more primes than expected?